# $\sigma(Y)$-measurable R.V. $X$ and Borel functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

I have to prove that if $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable function if and only if exists a Borel function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $X=f(Y)$.

The "if" part is simple.

I can prove the "only if" part by using the monotone class theorem for functions.
But there should be a simpler way... and I cannot find it.

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Using something like that is the usual approach. Or using the "usual machinery": indicator functions, simple functions, general measurable functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this that answer very clearly to my question [Measurability of one Random Variable with respect to Another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60939/measurability-of-one-random-variable-with-respect-to-another) (it was not in the related questions).

I was searching that straightforward constructive proof that gives "Nate Eldredge", not the abstract proof with the monotone class theorem.