# Measurability of random variables on the general spaces

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider random variables:
\begin{align}
X&:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to(E,\mathcal{E}),\\
Y&:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to(E_1,\mathcal{E}_1).
\end{align}
If $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, when does exist $h:E\to E_1$, s.t. $Y=h(X)$?

This clearly true if $X,Y$ are real-valued: [Measurability of one Random Variable with respect to Another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60939/measurability-of-one-random-variable-with-respect-to-another?noredirect=1&lq=1). What assumptions would be needed to reach the same conclusion for general $E,E_1$? I was thinking of *separability* of $E_1$, e.g. $E_1$ is Polish. Highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's important is $E_1$. As you observe, the propostion is true if $E_1$ is the real line equipped with the Borel sets. More generally, if $(E_1,\mathcal E_1)$ is measurably isomorphic to a Borel subset of the real line, then the proposition is true by composition with the isomorphism. In particular, any Polish $E_1$ is okay.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, do you actually mean I need $(E_1,\mathcal{E}_1)$ to be measurably isomorphic to a Borel subset of $E$, rather than a real line (since $X$ is $E$-valued)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.