# If $\mathbb{E}[X|Y] =X$ for $X,Y$ Gaussian, what is $p(x|y)$?

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, gaussian

Assume that we have two r.v. $X,Y$ that are marginally Gaussian distributed (we don't know about the joint distribution), and assume that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y] = X$ (i.e. $X$ is $Y$-measurable).

Does this mean that necessarily mean that $X=f(Y)$ for some deterministic $f$?

What do we know about the conditional density $p(x|y)$? Can it even be non-degenerate? It seems like it can not be a Gaussian, because then one would have $X|Y \sim \mathcal{N}(x;x,\sigma)$ which does not make sense.

Comment: It means that $X=f(Y)$ with probability 1, for some deterministic and Borel measurable $f$, that is $$P[\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)=f(Y(\omega))]=1$$  For example suppose $Y$ is Gaussian and $X=5Y+2$ almost surely.  Then $X$ is Gaussian, and $X$ is almost surely a linear function of $Y$.

Comment: How would one proof the 'only if' part for the deterministic function, so to speak? And, since both $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian, does this essentially mean that $f$ has to be affine linear?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60939/measurability-of-one-random-variable-with-respect-to-another) is what you're looking for?

Comment: There are standard examples to show $f$ is not necessarily linear, for example let $Y \sim N(0,1)$ and $$X=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} Y &\mbox{if $|Y|\leq 1$} \\ -Y & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$$ Then $X=f(Y)$ for a nonlinear function $f$ and $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed $N(0,1)$.

Comment: @angryavian yes this looks good